# Play2 Framework beginner. Get all the selected elements from <select>

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have added to my webpage the select2 mutliple select box.
https://select2.github.io/examples.html#multiple

[looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICOKK.png)

How can I grab all the selected elements from this select field to add them to the array?(I limited the number of selects to 5) Thanks!

Here is my code (I am using neo4j graph database):

Html form:

```
<select class="form-control select2-multi" name="interest" multiple="multiple">
    @for(interest <- interests){
        <option value="@interest.interestId">@interest.interestName</option>
    }
</select>
```

BusyUser model:

```
@Entity
public class    BusyUser {
public long id;
@Id
@Constraints.Required(message = "*")
@Constraints.Email(message = "?")
public String user;
@Constraints.Required(message = "*")
@Column(unique=true)
public String visibleUsername;
//@Transient
public String password;

//@Constraints.Required(message = "*")
public String name;
//@Constraints.Required(message = "*")
@Constraints.Email(message = "?")
@Column(unique=true)
public String mail;

public Boolean active;
@Formats.DateTime(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
public Date lastLogin;

public String authToken;
public String language;

public BusyUser(){}

public BusyUser(Node node)
{
    this.id=node.getId();
    this.password=(String)node.getProperty(ModelGraphProperty.BusyUser.Password,"");
    this.mail=(String)node.getProperty(ModelGraphProperty.BusyUser.Mail,"");
    this.user=(String)node.getProperty(ModelGraphProperty.BusyUser.User,"");
    this.visibleUsername=(String)node.getProperty(ModelGraphProperty.BusyUser.VisibleUsername,"");
    this.user=(String)node.getProperty(ModelGraphProperty.BusyUser.UserName,"");
    this.language=(String)node.getProperty(ModelGraphProperty.BusyUser.Language,"");
    this.authToken=(String)node.getProperty(ModelGraphProperty.BusyUser.Token,"");
}
```

Users.class where I am grabbing the form data:

```
private static final Form<BusyUser> userForm = Form.form(BusyUser.class);


//my save method

public static Result save()
{
    //the list of interests that I am grabbing from the database 
    List<Interest> interests= NeoDataProvider.getInterests(play.api.i18n.Lang.defaultLang().language());

    Http.MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();

    try {
        Form<BusyUser> boundForm = userForm.bindFromRequest();
        if(boundForm.hasErrors()) {
            flash("error", "!");
            return badRequest(createuser.render(boundForm, interests));
        }

        BusyUser user = boundForm.get();
        user.mail=user.user;
        user.active=true;
        user.lastLogin=new Date();
        user.password=BusyUser.bytesToHex(BusyUser.getSha512(user.password));

        Node nodeEvent = null;
        GraphDatabaseService db= Neo4JHelper.getDatabase();
        try ( Transaction tx = db.beginTx() )
        {
            Index<Node> userIndex = db.index().forNodes(ModelIndex.UsersSecurity);

            nodeEvent = db.createNode();
            nodeEvent.setProperty(ModelGraphProperty.BusyUser.Active, true);
            nodeEvent.setProperty(ModelGraphProperty.BusyUser.Mail, user.mail);
            nodeEvent.setProperty(ModelGraphProperty.BusyUser.Password, user.password);
            nodeEvent.setProperty(ModelGraphProperty.BusyUser.User, user.mail);
            nodeEvent.setProperty(ModelGraphProperty.BusyUser.VisibleUsername, user.visibleUsername);
            Node res=userIndex.putIfAbsent(nodeEvent, ModelGraphProperty.BusyUser.Mail, nodeEvent.getProperty(ModelGraphProperty.BusyUser.Mail));
            userIndex.add(nodeEvent, ModelGraphProperty.BusyUser.Password, nodeEvent.getProperty(ModelGraphProperty.BusyUser.Password));
            userIndex.add(nodeEvent, ModelGraphProperty.BusyUser.User, nodeEvent.getProperty(ModelGraphProperty.BusyUser.User));

            //userIndex.putIfAbsent(nodeEvent,ModelGraphProperty.BusyUser.Mail,user.mail);
            tx.success();
        }

        db.shutdown();

        flash("success",
                String.format("Successfully added user %s", user.user));

        return redirect(routes.Application.login());
    }catch(Exception ex){
        flash("error", "!");
        return badRequest(createuser.render(userForm, interests));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply read all Multiselect data just in place of name="interestedIn" in your form write `name="intrestedIn[]"` and declare `List<Long> intrestedIn= new ArrayList<Long>();` in your BusyUser.java after that you can iterate through list and get data like

```
String value=null;
for(int i=0;i<intrestedIn.size();i++){
value=intrestedIn.get(i);
//do whatever you want to do with this value
System.out.println(value);
}
```

Comment: it does not assign automatically the array fro mthe form to the interestedIn arrayList from my model. How do I add the elements from the request to the arrayList?